# Static pages return 404 in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I've been testing out the Google App Engine SDK using Golang and I'm having issues serving a static html page. If I add the content in the `app.yaml` under handlers that is fine but when trying to route it from inside my Go application; trying out the url `http://localhost:8080/tr` the page returns 404.

My file system is setup as:

```
/main.go
/app.yaml
/testRoute.html
```

My main `app.go` looks like this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func init() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", index)
    r.HandleFunc("/tr", testRoute)
    http.Handle("/", r)
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   //No Issues here 
   fmt.Fprint(w, "Main Index.")
}

func testRoute(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { 
    http.FileServer(http.Dir("testRoute.html")).ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

Comment: When you get the 404 - is the file still matched by a static file handler pattern inside `app.yaml`? If so - then the issue may be that a file by default is considered either a static artifact or an app-readable file. If you want both then you need to explicitly set the `application_readable` flag in `app.yaml`.

Comment: I've updated the app.yaml to include a handler for the files (placed in a static folder) with application readable; I can access the index file from the browser directly but when using the /tr route I still get a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use Go handlers to serve static files (unless you want to incorporate other logic such as advanced logging or counting).

You may define static file handlers in your app's configuration file `app.yaml`. This is detailed in the official docs: [**Static file handlers**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Go_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers)

> Static files are files to be served directly to the user for a given URL, such as images, CSS stylesheets, or JavaScript source files. Static file handlers describe which files in the application directory are static files, and which URLs serve them.
>
> For efficiency, App Engine stores and serves static files separately from application files. Static files are not available in the application's file system by default. This can be changed by setting the `application_readable` option to `true`.
>
> Static file handlers can be defined in two ways: as a directory structure of static files that maps to a URL path, or as a pattern that maps URLs to specific files.

To make AppEngine automatically serve a static file, add this entry to your `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /tr
  static_files: testRoute.html
  upload: testRoute.html
```

To make a whole directory of static files (including subfolders, recursively) to be served automatically, add this entry to `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets
```

Comment: Thanks icza. This helped a lot; is the best practice to re-load one of the app.yaml url paths using the http.FileServer?

Comment: @hairyCode What do you mean by _"re-load"_?

Comment: When inside the Go application I want to change to a different static location mentioned in the app.yaml handlers

Comment: @hairyCode I'm still not sure I understand what you want to do. You want to change/modify the response of a static file? You can't do that. If you want something to change (varying), then it should not be a static file, but that should be served entirely by your Go handler.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; let's say depending on the Go application's function I want to point the user to either static html page 1.html or 2.html; I don't want to modify the static content just parse the user to that page.

Comment: @hairyCode The URL to which static files are mapped is the `url:` line in the `app.yaml`. E.g. in the above example `/tr` will serve the `testRoute.html`. The path `/assets/logo.jpg` will serve the `assets/logo.jpg` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help icza. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using the ServeFile method; this also works with folders (eg "/assets/testRoute.html")

```
func testRoute(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { 
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "testRoute.html")
}
```