# Correct way to read file in Go AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

What's the correct way to read a file using Google AppEngine ([Go](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go))?

In Java I read there are `context.getResourceAsStream`, is there any equivalent function for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read from files on App Engine the same way you can read from files in a Go app running on your computer.

Some things to keep in mind:

- You should use *relative* file paths instead of absolute. The working directory is the root folder of your app (where the `app.yaml` file resides).
- Only files that are *application* files can be read by Go code, so if you want to read a file from Go code, the file must not be matched by a static file pattern (or if it must be available as a static file too, `application_readable` option must be specified at the static file handler which includes/applies to the file, [details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29288854/1705598)).

The latter is detailed on the [Application configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig) page, Section [Static file handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Go_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers). Quoting the relevant part:

> For efficiency, App Engine stores and serves static files separately from application files. Static files are not available in the application's file system. If you have data files that need to be read by the application code, the data files must be application files, and must not be matched by a static file pattern.

So let's say you have a folder `data` in your app's root (next to `app.yaml`), and a file `list.txt` in it. You may read its content like this:

```
if content, err := ioutil.Readfile("data/list.txt"); err != nil {
    // Failed to read file, handle error
} else {
    // Success, do something with content
}
```

Or if you want / need an [io.Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) ([`os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) implements `io.Reader` along with many other):

```
f, err := os.Open("data/list.txt") // For read access.
if err != nil {
    // Failed to open file, log / handle error
    return
}
defer f.Close()
// Here you may read from f
```

**Related questions:**

[Google App Engine Golang no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285670/google-app-engine-golang-no-such-file-or-directory)

[Static pages return 404 in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638518/static-pages-return-404-in-google-app-engine)

[How do I store the private key of my server in google app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629056/how-do-i-store-the-private-key-of-my-server-in-google-app-engine)